# Incorrect Rails Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
[******@s2 rails_apps]$ gem install -V rails -v=3 --no-rdoc --no-ri
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Found
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz 
304 Not Modified
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
connection reset after 2 requests, retrying
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Found
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
Installing gem rails-3.0.0
/home/******/ruby/gems/gems/rails-3.0.0/bin/rails
/home/******/ruby/gems/bin/rails
Successfully installed rails-3.0.0
1 gem installed
[******@s2 rails_apps]$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.14
[******@s2 rails_apps]$
```

why i cannot see Rails 3.0.0 ? I'm on Debian system if that is of any help.

Comment: Uninstall the old Rails version first or use RVM to manage your gemsets: http://beginrescueend.com/

Comment: Check your path. what is the output of `which rails`

Comment: what is the output of `gem list rails`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not v3 it's v3.0.0:

```
gem install -V rails -v=3.0.0 --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Comment: His output shows: `Successfully installed rails-3.0.0` so it looks like it matched it correctly

Comment: but it says `Successfully installed rails-3.0.0`. So I guess Rails 3.0.0 is installed.